# iPhone app not found on iPad

Tags: ipad

I have the Lorex baby monitoring system. My wife and I were in the market for a system that allowed us to use our mobile devices for remote viewing, so we went to our App stores on our phones and found the Lorex Care app. We now have the system and (though not great) the app works to our satisfaction. Tried to install it on my wife's iPad but it only finds Lorex apps for security monitoring but not the one solely for the baby monitor. I want to know if there is a way to "extract" the program (like an apk) from my iPhone and install it on her pad.

Comment: Does the app support both iPhone and iPad? If it does, it should be fine just searching for it in the App Store; if not, you may need to choose iPhone apps while searching on the App Store on your iPad. There is no way to extract an ipa and put it onto a different device.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the App Store on your iPad. Search for "Lorex Care." In the upper left corner (see screen shot), you can change "iPad Only" to "iPhone Only." Then the app will appear. If you touch "Lorex Care," it says it will work on the iPad. (The below screen shot came from my iPad.)

[image: Lorex Care]